# При клике на ссылку присвоить переменной значение вложенного инпута

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Есть страница с несколькими элементами. Выглядит так:

```
<a class="buytocredit1">
    <img src="/about/3.png">
    <input class="el1" name="element_id" type="hidden" value="<?=$arElement["ID"]?>">
</a>
```

Таких ссылок 10-15 на странице.

И есть скрипт jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buytocredit1').live('click', function() {
    var productid = $('.buytocredit1 .el1').val;
    //alert(productid);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Подскажите с тем, как при клике на ссылку присвоить переменной "productid" значение вложенного инпута name="element_id".

Answer (score 3):

Нашел сам.

```
 var productid = $(this).children('.el1').val();
```